# Access to html widget from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

I'd like to integrate the Tawk.to widget into my angularjs application.

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $_Tawk_API={},
            $_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();

        (function(){
            var s1=document.createElement("script"),
                s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];

            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/552e2462fd29683e1f71e7c8/default';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
        })();
    </script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

That widget is loaded asynchronously.
I just need to invoke the method `Tawk_API.toggle()`
Watching the `$_Tawk_API` object, is a possible solution ?
I don't know how I can reference the `$_Tawk_API` object from my angular controller.

Any advice ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don`t you just add the code into the controller?

Comment: I could use the event 
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
 //place your code here
};
but the Tawk_API reference  is always undefined. It's because is loaded async.

Comment: Alexandr, the problem is that I don't know when the Tawk_API reference is ready to be called from my code.

Comment: @AndreaBorgogelliAvveduti How did you add the Tawk_API reference?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my solutions:

AngularJS solution:

```
// inside the controller
angular.element($window).bind('load', function() {
  // here not only the page is loaded, 
  // but also all asynchronous requests are completed
  Tawk_API.toggle(); // I can call any api methods
}
```

JQuery solution:

```
 $(window).on('load', function(){
   // here not only the page is loaded, 
   // but also all asynchronous requests are completed
   Tawk_API.toggle(); // I can call any api methods;
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, where does Tawk_API come from in angular?